# Parentheses in block variables

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.9.3, parentheses, splat

Given

```
a = [[:a, :b, :c]]
```

1) I understand this

```
a.each{|(x, y), z| p z} # => :b
```

that there are two variables `(x, y)` and `z`, so the third element `:c` is thrown away, and `z` matches `:b`. And I understand this

```
a.each{|(x, y), z| p y} # => nil
```

that `(x, y)` matches `:a`, and since it is not an array, there are no elements to it, and so `y` matches `nil`.

But how does

```
a.each{|(x, y), z| p x} # => :a
```

work? I expect `nil` to be returned.

2) Why are the return values like this?

```
a.each{|(x, y)| p x} #=> :a
a.each{|(x, y)| p y} #=> :b
```

I expect them to both return `nil`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because of the syntax of *parallel assignment*.

```
a = [[:a, :b, :c]]
```

So `a.each` has only one element to iterate, which is `[:a, :b, :c]`.

In the first case:

```
(x, y), z = [:a, :b, :c]
#=> x == :a, y == nil, z == :b
```

Here `(x, y)` is an array to match the first element `:a`, and `x` gets it, then `z` simply matches the second element `:b`.

And in the second case:

```
(x, y) = [:a, :b, :c]
#=> x == :a, y == :b
```

Here `(x, y)` as an entire array matches the array `[:a, :b, :c]`, so `x` and `y` get `:a` and `:b` respectively.

This is just like requiring the "args + optional args (keyword args) + rest args" combination match provided arguments. It is just smart enough to take arguments by sequence.

Another smart example:

```
(a,b) = 1,2
=> [1, 2] # array match
#=> a == 1, b == 2

(a,b)=[1,2]
=> [1, 2] # array match
#=> a == 1, b == 2
```

In either case above, it will simply make the best guess on what it should take.

Comment: Okay, so in the first case, the smart assignment takes place twice, and in the second part of it, (x, y) = :a results in x = :a and y = nil. I got it.

Comment: Nice. I use this all the time without realizing it was connected with parallel assignment. I also found a blog that calls it "destructuring".